# Lock a table during multiple statements in a stored procedure

Tags: teradata

I am looking to implement the equivalent of snapshot isolation with a Teradata transaction.  Oracle supports this type of isolation, but Teradata does not (at least not in versions 14 or prior that I am aware of).  The goal is to create a procedure that deletes a table's contents and then repopulates it all while preventing other users from reading from/writing to the table.

I came across the `begin request` statement which, according to my understanding, allows the optimizer to know about all the various table locks within the request.

I wrote the procedure below, but don't know how to reliably debug it as easy as I would if I were testing thread locking in a .NET application (easy to set breakpoints and monitor other threads).  In Teradata, not sure if what I wrote here will properly lock `mydb.destinationtable` exclusively for the duration of the procedure.  Is this correct?

**Edit:** I'll add that the procedure does work.  It's just being able to properly time a SELECT while it's doing its DELETE/INSERT.

```
replace procedure mydb.myproc()
begin
    begin request

    locking mydb.destinationtable for exclusive
    delete mydb.destinationtable;

    locking mydb.destinationtable for exclusive
    insert into mydb.destinationtable
    select * from mydb.sourcetable;

    end request;
end;
```

Comment: 1. Use views, not tables, for reading data. 2. Drop views while loading. 3. Recreate views when load is done.  You could also use mload, which handles all the locking for you, as far as I know.

Comment: Why not use a TASM to deny (or delay) requests against the table (or database) that is being loaded during ETL? Not ideal solution but addresses lock isolation. Alternatively, could you use a queue table and a column defined with a nested SELECT statement in the views which end users access the table which attempts to access the token in the queue table. If the token is missing, the query goes into a QT_DELAYED state.

Comment: @RobPaller In researching TASM and looking at examples of queue tables, seems like a lot of setup and/or boilerplate is involved.  Not saying they wont' work, but am simply seeking a means to, within a stored procedure (ie, not BTEQ or the like), 1) put an exclusive lock on a table, 2) execute multiple statements (not even necessarily against locked table), and then 3) release the lock.  dnoeth's answer *appears* to confirm that my OP code will do exactly that, though with the potential performance hit of transient journaling which I don't quite understand yet.

Comment: Just a suggestion about how to debug the behaviour. Create a fake table, and insert into your procedure an update on this fake table where you would usually set a breakpoint. Before launching the procedure, lock the fake table from another session. This way your procedure will block where you need and you can test the effect of locking your destinationtable on other users.

Comment: @Insac I like that idea a lot.  How would I go about locking a table for an indefinite period of time?

Answer (score 0):

`BEGIN REQUEST`/`END REQUEST` creates a so-called *Multi Statement Request* (MSR) which is the same a submitting both requests in SQL Assistant using F9.

To see the plan run this with F9:

```
EXPLAIN
locking mydb.destinationtable for exclusive
delete mydb.destinationtable;

insert into mydb.destinationtable
select * from mydb.sourcetable;
```

or in BTEQ:

```
EXPLAIN
locking mydb.destinationtable for exclusive
delete mydb.destinationtable
;insert into mydb.destinationtable
select * from mydb.sourcetable;
```

Btw, the 2nd lock is redundant.

**But**. When you run Delete & InsSel as a single transaction both will be Transient Journalled. Which is *much* slower than seperate requests.

A more common way to do this is to use two copies of the target table and base access on Views not Tables:

```
-- no BEGIN/END REQUEST
insert into mydb.destinationtable_2
select * from mydb.sourcetable;

-- there's just a short dictionary lock
-- all requests against the view submitted before the replace use the old data
-- and all submitted after the new data
replace view myview as 
select * from mydb.destinationtable_2;

delete from mydb.destinationtable_1;
```

Now your SP only needs the logic to switch between 1 & 2 (based on *table [not] empty*)

Comment: I really want to avoid swapping tables/views.  Is there no way to put an exclusive lock on a table throughout the duration of a stored procedure?  As far as the redundant lock, are you saying that placing the lock only during the DELETE will also apply the lock to the INSERT?  As for being transient journaled, is there a way to run both as separate statements under the same transaction while also being able to lock my table exclusively until the transaction is committed?

Comment: As for why I don't want to swap sources it's beause I want to emulate Oracle's snapshot isolation.  Maybe behind the scenes Oracle is doing the same thing, but it's implicit.  I don't want to have emulate that type of isolation in Teradata manually.

Comment: When you do a MSR you send both DEL & INS/SEL in a single request to the optimizer, thus the optimizer knows that both statements access the same table and applies the most restrictive lock. Why do you think you needs snapshot isolation, isn't it a warehouse anyway? What kind of data are you processing and how often will you run that procedure?

Comment: I am probably doing a bad thing by continuing to use the term "snapshot isolation".  In Oracle, you can run several queries within a transaction.  Until the change is committed, anyone querying the data will see it as it existed before the transaction was opened and only see the changes when it's committed.  In my case here, if someone queries the data after the DELETE but before the INSERT, their query would return 0 results.  I want to mitigate this risk by locking the destination table exclusively so that all queries against it must wait until the lock is released.

Comment: It also takes care of all the boilerplate of having to swap views, manage which view to use based on counts, making sure all your load table DDL is in sync whenever you need to add a new column, etc.  Basically, I want to lock a table exclusively, run as many SQL statements as I wish (doesn't even have to be in a transation), and then remove the lock when I am done.

Comment: Did you really Delete & re-Insert *huge* tables in Oracle within a single transaction? Of course you can also run several queries within a transaction in Teradata (`BT; .... ET;` or Multi Statement Requests) and if you specify an Exclusive Lock nobody will be able to read data (not even using an Access Lock). Locks are released after commit, if you want to do multiple transactions you need a View-based access (revoke the Select right before you start and grant back when finished using a simple SP). Btw, 15.10 introduces *Load Isolated Tables*.

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment, it doesn't have to be a transaction.  I just need to be able to lock a table exclusively across multiple statements.  From your comment, it seems as though the proc in my OP is written properly, albeit with a redundant lock which I will remove.  You also mention the performance impact of transient journaling.  If the only other alternative is the boilerplate of swapping load tables then I think I am willing to cope with that.